# How to remove common words from list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a large number of "groups" of words. If any of the words from one group appears both in column A and column B, I want to remove the words in the group from the two columns. How do I loop over all the groups (i.e. over the sublists in the list)?

The flawed code below only removes the common words from the last group, not all three groups (lists) in stuff. [I first create an indicator if one of the words from the groups is in the string, and then create another indicator if both strings have a word from the group. Only for the pairs of A and B where both have a word from the group, I remove the particular group words.]

How do I correctly specify the loop?

EDIT:
In my suggested code, each loop restarted with the original columns instead looping over the columns with words removed from the previous group(s).

The solution suggestions are more elegant and neat but remove the words if they are part of another word (e.g. the word 'foo' is correctly removed from 'foo hello' but incorrectly also removed from 'foobar'.

```
# Input data:

data = {'A': ['summer time third grey abc', 'yellow sky hello table', 'fourth autumnwind'],
        'B': ['defg autumn times fourth table', 'not red skies second garnet', 'first blue chair winter']
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['A', 'B'])  

                            A                               B
0  summer time third grey abc  defg autumn times fourth table
1      yellow sky hello table     not red skies second garnet
2           fourth autumnwind         first blue chair winter
```

```
# Groups of words to be removed:

colors = ['red skies', 'red sky', 'yellow sky', 'yellow skies', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'grey']
seasons = ['summer times', 'summer time', 'autumn times', 'autumn time', 'spring', 'summer', 'winter', 'autumn']
numbers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

stuff = [colors, seasons, numbers]



# Code below only removes the last list in stuff (numbers):

def fA(S,y):
    for word in listed:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', S):
            y = 1
    return y


def fB(T,y):
    for word in listed:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', T):
            y = 1
    return y



def fARemove(S):
    for word in listed:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', S):
            S=re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), ' ', S)
    return S



def fBRemove(T):
    for word in listed:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', T):
            T=re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), ' ', T)
    return T

for listed in stuff:

    df['A_Ind'] = 0
    df['B_Ind'] = 0

    df['A_Ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: fA(x.A, x.A_Ind), axis=1)
    df['B_Ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: fB(x.B, x.B_Ind), axis=1)

    df['inboth'] = 0
    df.loc[((df.A_Ind == 1) & (df.B_Ind == 1)), 'inboth'] = 1

    df['A_new'] = df['A']
    df['B_new'] = df['B']

    df.loc[df.inboth == 1, 'A_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: fARemove(x.A), axis=1)
    df.loc[df.inboth == 1, 'B_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: fBRemove(x.B), axis=1)


    del df['inboth']
    del df['A_Ind']
    del df['B_Ind']
    
    df['A_new'] = df['A_new'].str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ')
    df['A_new'] = df['A_new'].str.strip()
    df['B_new'] = df['B_new'].str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ')
    df['B_new'] = df['B_new'].str.strip()
```

Expected output is:

```
         A_new              B_new
0     grey abc         defg table
1  hello table   no second garnet
2   autumnwind  blue chair winter
```

Comment: I think you want to say "if any of the words from any group appears in either column A or B", because, with your current wording, your expected output is wrong. "Summer" appears only in column A, but you still removed it...

Comment: I would honestly do something similar, but using list comprehensions. `[word for word in x if word not in flatten([l for l in stuff if (len([e for e in l if e in x.A]) > 0 and len([e for e in l if e in x.B]) >0)])]` where flatten is a simple flatten operator.

Comment: No, the expected output is correct. In the first row, there are words from the seasons group in both A (summer third grey abc) and in B (defg autumn fourth table). So since there are season words in both A and B, "summer" should be removed from A and "autumn" removed from B. In the same way, numbers words "third" and "fourth" should be removed from A and B in the first row. This in comparison to the third row, where "blue" is not removed from B since there is no colours word in column A.

Comment: This is also why I don't think flatten lists will work. Using flatten would remove all the words everywhere. I instead need to remove the words in one group only if words from the same group appear in the same row of A and B.

Comment: can I assume your words are separated by single spaces? It would be much easier to use string functions than re

Comment: @BingWang yes, I can easily arrange the words as separated with single spaces.

Comment: @pandini I didn't want to say that the output is wrong, but that it is correct and the formulation is wrong.

Comment: @pandini I will make a proper example / answer soon

Answer (score 2):

this needs python 3.7+ to work (otherwise more codes are needed). Based on your list of keywords, I think you are trying to prioritize multi words matching.

```
dummy=0
def splitter(text):
    global dummy
    text=text.strip()
    if not text:
        return []
    for n,s in enumerate(stuff):
        for keyword in s:
            p=text.find(keyword)
            if p>=0:
                return splitter(text[:p])+[((dummy,keyword),n)]+splitter(text[p+len(keyword):])
    else:
        return [((dummy,text),-1)]

def remover(row):
    A=dict(splitter(row['A']))
    B=dict(splitter(row['B']))
    s=set(A.values()).intersection(set(B.values()))
    return [' '.join([k[1] for k,v in A.items() if v<0 or v not in s]),' '.join([k[1] for k,v in B.items() if v<0 or v not in s])]
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.apply(remover, axis=1).to_list(), columns=['newA','newB'])],  axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this @BingWang. Unfortunately, my list has composed words so the solution will actually not work. Apologies for the misinformation about the words in the groups in the lists being separated by single spaces. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @pandini I updated to use recursive. The variable dummy is to create unique keys in case you have repeating words in a single phrase

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re

flatten_list = lambda l: [item for subl in l for item in subl]
def remove_recursive(s, l):
    while len(l) > 0:
        s = s.replace(l[0], '')
        l = l[1:]

    return re.sub(r'\ +', ' ', s).strip()


df['A_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_recursive(x.A, flatten_list([l for l in stuff if (len([e for e in l if e in x.A]) > 0 and len([e for e in l if e in x.B]) > 0)])), axis = 1)
df['B_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_recursive(x.B, flatten_list([l for l in stuff if (len([e for e in l if e in x.A]) > 0 and len([e for e in l if e in x.B]) > 0)])), axis = 1)

df.head()

#            A_new              B_new
# 0  time grey abc         defg table
# 1    hello table  not second garnet
# 2           wind         blue chair
```

This is similar code to the one in comments, using a recursive lambda for matching words and a flattened list to figure the words in the lists that match in both columns.

Comment: The list comprehension is great and does lead to shorter code

Comment: @BingWang you can also optimise if yoou compute the common part of the comprehension first, reducing the search time by half, I think

Comment: I just discovered another problem. If any of the listed words is part of a longer word, it is incorrectly removed. (This is why the regex using \b was necessary in the first place. I will edit the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code from the original question using regex r'\b{}\b', corrected for looping over the latest strings and not the original strings.

```
# Groups of words to be removed:

colors = ['red skies', 'red sky', 'yellow sky', 'yellow skies', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'grey']
seasons = ['summer times', 'summer time', 'autumn times', 'autumn time', 'spring', 'summer', 'winter', 'autumn']
numbers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

stuff = [colors, seasons, numbers]


df['A_new'] = df['A']
df['B_new'] = df['B']


def f_indicator(S,y):
    for word in listed:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', S):
            y = 1
    return y


def fRemove(S):
    for word in listed:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', S):
            S=re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), ' ', S)
    return S


for listed in stuff:

    df['A_Ind'] = 0
    df['B_Ind'] = 0

    df['A_Ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: f_indicator(x.A_new, x.A_Ind), axis=1)
    df['B_Ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: f_indicator(x.B_new, x.B_Ind), axis=1)

    df['inboth'] = 0
    df.loc[((df.A_Ind == 1) & (df.B_Ind == 1)), 'inboth'] = 1



    df.loc[df.inboth == 1, 'A_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: fRemove(x.A_new), axis=1)
    df.loc[df.inboth == 1, 'B_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: fRemove(x.B_new), axis=1)


    del df['inboth']
    del df['A_Ind']
    del df['B_Ind']

    
    df['A_new'] = df['A_new'].str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ')
    df['A_new'] = df['A_new'].str.strip()
    df['B_new'] = df['B_new'].str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ')
    df['B_new'] = df['B_new'].str.strip()

del df['A']
del df['B']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         A_new              B_new
0     grey abc         defg table
1  hello table  not second garnet
2   autumnwind  blue chair winter
```